# mysql - How to calculate mode several times in a table

Tags: mysql, count, max

Im trying to get the mode (the value that appears most often in a set of data) of price for each store in the following table

```
create table t_products (
store_id int,
product varchar(20),
price int
)
```

I already have this query which retrieves all the ocurrences of each price in each store

```
SELECT store_id, price, count(price)
FROM t_products
GROUP BY store_id, price
ORDER BY count(price) DESC;
```

What else is missing? I was trying to use max() function to get the highest price for each store in several ways with no success.

Thanks in advance
PD this is the result of my current query.

```
store_id|price|count(price)
2          40      5
1          70      5
2          90      4
3          60      2
1          60      1
3          50      1
3          80      1
1          50      1
```

I only want to keep

```
 store    price
    2      40 
    1      70 
    3      60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tmp.store_id, tmp.price from (
    SELECT store_id, price
    FROM t_products
    GROUP BY store_id, price
    ORDER BY count(price) DESC
) as tmp
group by tmp.store_id
```

Good luck )

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT store_id, value
FROM (SELECT store_id, value, count(value) c
      FROM t_products
      GROUP BY store_id, value
      ORDER  BY count(value) DESC) ds
GROUP BY store_id
HAVING max(ds.c);
```